# value of the integration Is dependent on c?

Tags: real-analysis, definite-integrals

$f:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be continuous, then $$ \int_{0}^{1}f(x)e^{-x}dx=?$$

I understand I need to do integration by parts, taking $f(x)$ in 2nd function, so that I can apply mean value theorem of Integral calculus $\int_{0}^{1}f(x)=(1-0)f(c)$ for some $c\in(0,1)$, but I am not able to get the final answer

will the answer b from the following

1. $f'(0)-f'(1)e^{-1}$
2. $f(c)(1-e^{-1})$
3. $e^{-c}\int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx$

Comment: Could you bit a little more precise in asking your question? I can't tell what you want here.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need integration by parts. Option 1 is a red herring: there is no way for the integral to be independent of the values of $f$ in the interior of the interval. This question tests your knowledge of the [Mean value theorem for integrals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#First_mean_value_theorem_for_integration) (to the extent that a multiple-choice question can do such a thing). Both 2 and 3 look like an application of this theorem, but one is legitimate and one is not.

> Stop and think before reading further.

To understand which, you should recall that the functions that remains in the integral must have constant sign (it's considered to be a "weight", most often nonnegative). So we can apply MVT by leaving $e^{-x}$ inside. We cannot do the same with $f$, since there is no information about its sign.